# Align navigation div with edge of responsive slideshow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

The goal is to have the right edge of the upper navigation (navbar-right) align with the right edge of the image slideshow below as the address text does now, without ever going outside the slideshow's right edge.

The trouble is that the address div is within the responsive slideshow div, allowing it to stay right-aligned when the grid size changes and "snaps" over a number of pixels. Is there some way to integrate the upper navigation into the responsive grid "snapping"?

Website draft: http://parkerrichard.com/studiogreen/html/parks.html

Desired alignment: [image: screen of desired alignenment]

HTML:

```
<body>
<!-- row 1: static navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png"></a>
        </div><!-- navbar toggle -->
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-stacked hidden-xs">
                <li><a href="process.html">PROCESS</a></li>
                <li><a href="office.html">OFFICE</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm mobile-nav">
                <li><a href="process.html">PROCESS</a></li>
                <li><a href="office.html">OFFICE</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li class="divider"><img src="img/nav-divider.jpg"></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/container -->
</nav><!--/navbar -->

<!-- row 2: body -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row centered">
        <!-- left sidebar -->
        <aside class="navbar-collapse collapse panel-group col-lg-4 col-med-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="schools.html">
                            SCHOOLS
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </aside>


        <!-- slideshow gallery -->          
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-7 pull-left">
            <div class="flexslider no-arrow">
                <ul class="slides">
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/parks/img-01.jpg" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/parks/img-02.jpg" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <address class="info-box temp-box temp-add pull-right">
            232 SIR FRANCIS DRAKE BLVD</br>
            SAN ANSELMO, CA 94960</br>
            415 721 0905
            </address>
        </div><!--/slideshow row -->
    </div><!--/body row -->
</div><!--/container -->
```

CSS:

```
    .container {
    width: 100%;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   General styles
   ========================================================================== */

html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
    font-family: "proxima-nova", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: .7px;
    color: #555;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

aside {
    z-index: 100;
}

address {
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: none;
}

.info-box {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 0px 0px 0 55px;
    display: none;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Navigation styles
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * Top nav section
 */

.navbar-header {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 0px!important;
}

.navbar .nav {
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 45px;
}

.navbar .nav > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #555;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .active > a, a:hover, a:active {
    color: #6CAA3D;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
    padding: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
}

.navbar-collapse {
    margin-top: -65px;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-color: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
    padding-top: 10px;
    overflow-y: visible;
    padding-left: 115px;
}

.logo {
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}

.navbar-right {
    padding: 15px 20px 0 0;
    margin-right: 16%;
}

.mobile-nav {
    width: 100px;
}

/*
 * flexslider styling 
 */

.flexslider {
    background:none !important;
    border:none !important;
    box-shadow:none !important;
}

.slides li img {
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;

    /*
     Introduced in IE 10.
     See http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/msUserSelect/
    */
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.flex-control-nav {
    text-align: right !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
}

.flex-control-paging li {
    margin: 0 0px 0 12px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the nav div into the responsive slideshow div and added a new style to place on the right edge.

Updated HTML:

```
<body>
    <!-- row 1: static navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png"></a>
            </div><!-- navbar toggle -->
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm mobile-nav">
                    <li><a href="process.html">PROCESS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="office.html">OFFICE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"><img src="img/nav-divider.jpg"></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/container -->
    </nav><!--/navbar -->

    <!-- row 1: body -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row centered">
            <!-- left sidebar -->
            <aside class="navbar-collapse collapse panel-group col-lg-4 col-med-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a href="schools.html">
                                SCHOOLS
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </aside>

            <!-- slideshow gallery -->
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-7">
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse plibt">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-xs">
                        <li><a href="process.html">PROCESS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="office.html">OFFICE</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="flexslider nodot no-arrow pull-left">
                    <ul class="slides">
                        <li>
                            <img src="img/home-slideshow/img-01.jpg" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="img/home-slideshow/img-02.jpg" />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- address row -->
                <address class="info-box pull-right">
                232 SIR FRANCIS DRAKE BLVD</br>
                SAN ANSELMO, CA 94960</br>
                415 721 0905
                </address>
            </div><!--/slideshow row -->
        </div><!--/body row -->
    </div><!--/container -->
```

Added CSS:

```
.plibt {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -150px;
    margin: 0 -22px 0px 0 !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    background: none;
}

.plibt li {
    padding: 15px 0px 15px 20px !important;
}

.plibt li a {
    background: none !important;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```